# Preview pdf file in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pdf

Is there a way to **preview a pdf** (in the console) when running a program with Python ?

There is [`preview-generator`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/preview-generator/0.2.2) library for Python 3 but I'm using Python 2.7.

Comment: It seems preview-generator leans on python-magick, which in turn outsources the hard work to ImageMagick. Presumably you could do the same thing, even in older Pythons.

Comment: Is it `text-only` pdf?

Comment: What do you mean by "preview a PDF in the console"? Do you mean that you want to generate it in a script, open it from the console, or view some kind of rendering of it in the console?

Comment: Yeah just render it in the console for terminal preview. I'm have a script that's crawling pdfs and I'd like to have a sneak peak of each one in my terminal while running my script.